# Installing WiFi Driver from Firmware Files

Tags: linux, wifi, firmware

I'm running NXP's Layerscape (Ubuntu Derivative) on a [LS1012A development board](https://www.nxp.com/design/software/qoriq-developer-resources/layerscape-frwy-ls1012a-board:FRWY-LS1012A). I have a PCIe [88W9098 WiFi card](https://www.embeddedartists.com/products/1xl-m-2-module/) (also made by NXP), and am having difficulty getting it to work with this board. NXP support has not been helpful on this topic, so am curious if anyone has experience compiling (creating?) Linux Drivers from WiFi Module firmware files. I obtained the [88W9098 Firmware Files](https://github.com/nxp-imx/imx-firmware/tree/lf-5.15.52_2.1.0/nxp/FwImage_9098_PCIE) from NXP's github repository and am running Linux Kernel 5.10.35 with Ubuntu 20.02. The firmware files I've obtained are for my correct Linux Kernel.

Does anyone know how to compile and install a WiFi driver from its firmware files? Any help would be greatly appreciated!